# What is the approximate age of Captain Jack Sparrow?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

I truly love this character. I want to know that how old Captain Jack Sparrow approximately is in the *Pirates of the Caribbean* series. Especially when he saves Elizabeth at Port Royal after she falls.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why especially when he saves Elizabeth? Do you have any reason to believe he is at a significantly different age at all the other moments in the movies?

Answer (score 1):

According to this page he was 40 when he died by the kraken:
[Jack Sparrow](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Sparrow) (Born 1700, Events of Part 2 was at 1740)

According to [this timeline](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Pirates_of_the_Caribbean_series) the saving of Elizabeth and his death happend in the same year, so he was 39 or 40.

Johnny Depp was 40 when playing in the first part of the movies, so I guess they estimated Sparrow's age by Johnny's age.

Comment: That page is making a guess with very little hard information:  "Estimation based on Johnny Depp's age during the filming of Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl, and the fact that Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides takes place in 1750, a few years after the events of Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End, itself a year and a few months after The Curse of the Black Pearl."

Comment: Hm, you are right. Not sure if someone can find an exact answer without estimation, i will leave my answer for now, so captainsac has at least some information

Comment: I believe Wikia is only resource available online for Pirates of carrebian universe

Comment: It also should be noted that OST takes place at 1750 and DMTNT 1751. So a lot of time passed between AWE (1729) & DMTNT (1751) -- Like 20 years!!

Answer (score -1):

Jack Sparrow was born in the year 1700 and CotBP happened in 1728 (Jack’s age is 28), DMC and AWE happened in 1729 (Jack’s age 29), and then OST and DMTNT were in 1750 and 1751( Jack’s age being 50 and 51).

Comment: It is better if you link the source that led to the year when Jack was born. Otherwise we have no means of trusting this answer